# Why does the background image not cover the whole page sometimes?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have an HTML page where I have an image as a background. Whenever I view the page on my iPhone 6, the background image sometimes doesn't cover the whole page. This happens only about 20% of the time and doesn't happen after reloading the page. It always happens when I clear cache and website data on my phone. This is the CSS to set it to the background(I got it from the web by searching "how to make a good CSS background image")

```
 html { /*Copied from the web*/
  background: url(img/sea.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}   

body{
    background: none;
}
```

The url of the page is msolonko.net/signup.php. [image: What the page looks like on my iPhone rarely]

As you can see on the image, there is white space below the login button. Why does the image work correctly sometimes, but rarely not? How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Changing resolutions of the image has no effect on the issue. 
I do not want the image to repeat. It looks good with just one image if the issue doesn't occur.

Also, if I cannot fix this issue, I will make the image only appear if it is a computer. If the device width is less than some threshold, I will just use a background color instead of image. I am still hoping I can fix this though.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions: Make it so the image repeats (turn no-repeat to repeat) or..
Increase the height of sky.jpg since sky.jpg is not tall enough to fit the phone.

So if I'm not mistaking (which I probably am), you should make your sky.jpg image 960 x 660 pix. Some average phone pixel resolutions at http://www.binvisions.com/articles/tablet-smartphone-resolutions-screen-size-list/

This should help! Sorry if it didn't.

EDIT: Did you at least try the techniques? (I'm new to Stack, I can't comment)

Comment: If it is not tall enough for a phone, how come it looks good 80% of the time, and doesn't fit the screen only rarely? If it was not tall enough, I assume the issue would always occur.

Comment: I will try the techniques and let you know what happens. I have a similar image on one of the other pages of my site, and it works without any problems. I will still try and tell you the result.

Comment: I experimented with different resolutions and the issue persisted.

Comment: you tried to put "repeat" instead? Try that instead of "no-repeat"

Answer (score 0):

edit the image before you load the page, make the correct size for it and there you got.
be recursive.
(i have the same problem and do it this way becouse i found no way to find a solution in the code.)
i use programs like photoshop and corel.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I was learning some CSS... CSS Code:

```
body {
    background-image:sky.jpg; /*or whatever*/
}
```

Should work...maybe.